# how to use open source software for my own only?

Tags: open-source, licensing

how can I use open source software that was published so all people can modify and upgrade it . can I update the software and then never publish my changes and just keep my modified version for me or for my company only or this violates something that I am missing ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about licensing

Comment: ...and it's unanswerable because it would depend on the software's license.

Comment: well sorry for that I didnt know and that what SO community should providev ? how can I edit the question then ? how to answer so others who  are like me can benefit .. not just voting .. instead of voting to close it guide me man

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing instead of directly about programming. **[See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274963/1402846)** for details and the **[help]** for more.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about licensing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open source software generally comes with a licence. There are many type of licences, some with constraints respect to companies using them (for example) and some complete free.

You have to read the licence in your case and find the rest of the answers there.